# Movie clip resolution changes when added to an input node in Compositor

Tags: node-editor, video

I'm using Blender as a video editor.

I want to remove the green screen background from my clip and replace it with my own image. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do that, but I'm hitting a snag almost before I start.

In the Compositor, I created an input (Movie clip) node and a viewer node, and connected them.

When I put my clip into the input node, the resolution changes. The face of the subject seems to be compressed horizontally, and the clip looks to be about 5:4 or 4:3 aspect ratio.

Resolution of my movie clip is 1920x1080, and that is the desired output resolution.

In Blender Properties tab, Dimensions are set to 1920 px x 1080 px (default).
Aspect ratio is 1:1

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Edit 1:

[image: Node Setup. Input node (movie clip) to viewer node]

Yes the image I will be compositing is 1920x1080, however the error occurs before I even connect the background image.

Edit 2: This is the second video I've made with Blender and the first had no issues like this (using the same camera) so I don't think it's a camera issue.

Comment: Is the resolution of the image you are compositing with the same 1920x1080? Please [edit] your question and add more information. An image of the current node setup would help to understand what the problem might be.

Comment: It is possible that you have an anamorphic image. That is where the camera records fewer pixels but instructs the playback app to stretch the image back out to original dimensions. If you open some media players they will indicate the actual pixel count and the displayed pixel count. Perhaps you need to use a Scale node > Render Size

Answer (score 1):

I used a Scale Node > Render Size as suggested by 3pointedit and it worked, still not sure how the problem was caused as I used this same camera before and had no issue. Thanks for the help though everyone!

Comment: You are probably dealing with a camera that uses an anamorphic format,. Where the pixel ratio is not 1:1.  My guess is that the camera is recording 1440x1080 pixels and that image gets stretched to 1920x1080 during playback.